# Boot fails after showing ubuntu screen and just sits on screen showing [OK]. Tried removing fglrx but still can't get it to go

Tags: compiz, ati, xorg, boot-failure, fglrx

Just all the sudden compiz failed and I couldn't get it to relauch so I rebooted the system. Ever since, after the Ubuntu login screen (with 5 round circles in the middle. It just goes to the next screen which is black with various tasks displaying [OK] at the end and freezes. I've switched over to a terminal session and removed fglrx and reinstalled xorg-default drivers. This didn't help because I had a suspicion it was an issue with X. Not sure where else to go but a reinstall. Any one have any ideas to try or to get further where the boot is failing.

Of note, when I reinstalled to the open source drivers, I got a screen saying hardware not detected properly and I hit ok to continue for one session. Then froze at the same screen again so appeared not to be to open source or proprietary drivers.

Link to screenshot after startx is run:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/udo7xxfpkg79w0h/2012-07-19%2012.41.11.jpg

Comment: Do you see any errors while running `startx` in the terminal session? If so, could you paste them (or send a photo, if you can't)?

Comment: @lkjoel - screenshot link added. That is as far as it gets which just shows a blank screen with an arrow.

Comment: So nothing happens after that? No display at all? And what's the `^@`?

Comment: @lkjoel - It forces me over to the x-windows (Ctrl-Alt-F7) but it's just a black screen with an arrow cursor on it that can move around. If I hit Ctrl-Alt-F1 i see what I took a photo of which 2 hours later now still hasn't changed on either screen. If I force close and do it again it hangs at the same spot. The ^@ is just from accidently hitting some keys on the keyboard so ignore that.

Comment: @lkjoel - If I boot into recovery mode. Even with failsafe graphics still a no go.

Comment: Oh, I see... Reboot and try this instead: `sudo service lightdm start`

Comment: @lkjoel - Ended up just doing a reinstall. During that had a similar problem and yeah that usually would kick it back to the main menu so it would work. When I cleared the compiz settings out from the home folder seemed fine. Then just reloaded them in with my exported file. Reckon it was something conflicting in compiz.

Comment: Oh ok, yeah, a reinstall usually does the trick ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had reinstalled the system but likely the stated answer of:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

will do the trick from having a similar error on another computer.

Answer (score -1):

Just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> OR <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it will show that Killing remaining process and book to your Profile...